# Increase efficiency and velocity autosuggestion algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, autosuggest

In my project, for inserting an **autosuggestion** function (also in presence of little insertion errors, like Google), I've created this class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Searcher {

private ArrayList<String> titoli;
private boolean multiThread;
private int numeroCore;
private Thread [] threads;
private int indice;
private String [] testoSplittato;
private SortedSet<String> risultati;
private final Runnable runnable;

public Searcher (ArrayList<String> titoli , boolean multiThread) {
    this.titoli = titoli;
    this.multiThread = multiThread;
    indice = 0;
    risultati = new TreeSet<String> ();
    numeroCore = multiThread ? Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() : 1;
    threads = new Thread [numeroCore];
    runnable = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run () {                    
            String prossimo;
            while ((prossimo = getProssimo ()) != null) {
                if (suggerimentoDaAggiungere (prossimo.toLowerCase()))
                    aggiungiRisultato (prossimo);
            }
        }
    };
    for (int i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
        threads [i] = new Thread (runnable);
    }
}

public Searcher (ArrayList<String> titoli) {
    this (titoli, false);
}

private synchronized void setIndice (int n) {
    indice = n;
}

private synchronized String getProssimo () {
    try {
        return titoli.get(indice++);
    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ioobe) {
        return null;
    }
}

public synchronized void aggiungiRisultato (String s) {
    risultati.add(s);
}

private boolean mancaUnaLettera (String a , String b) {
    int al = a.length() , bl = b.length();
    if (al < 2 || al >= bl)
        return false;

    //a più corta di b
    int primaLetteraSbagliata = -1;
    for (int i=0;i<al;i++) {
        if (a.charAt (i) != b.charAt(i)) {
            primaLetteraSbagliata = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return primaLetteraSbagliata >= 0 && (b.substring(0, primaLetteraSbagliata) + b.substring(primaLetteraSbagliata + 1)).indexOf(a) >= 0;
}

private boolean unaLetteraDiTroppo (String a , String b) {
    int al = a.length() , bl = b.length();
    if (al < 3 || al - 1 > bl)
        return false;

    //a più corta o stessa lunghezza di b
    int primaLetteraSbagliata = -1;
    for (int i=0;i<bl;i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
            primaLetteraSbagliata = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    //non sono sicurissimo di qui
    if (primaLetteraSbagliata == -1 && al + 1 == bl)
        return true;

    return primaLetteraSbagliata >= 0 && b.indexOf ((primaLetteraSbagliata > 0 ? a.substring(0 , primaLetteraSbagliata) : "") + (primaLetteraSbagliata + 1 < al ? a.substring(primaLetteraSbagliata + 1) : "") ) >= 0;
}

private boolean unaLetteraSbagliata (String a , String b) {
    int al = a.length() , bl = b.length();
    if (al < 3 || al > bl)
        return false;

    //a ha lunghezza >= di b
    int primaLetteraSbagliata = -1;
    for (int i=0;i<al;i++) {
        if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) {
            primaLetteraSbagliata = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    boolean ok = primaLetteraSbagliata + 1 < al;

    return primaLetteraSbagliata >= 0 && (b.substring(0, primaLetteraSbagliata) + (ok ? b.substring(primaLetteraSbagliata + 1) : "")).indexOf(a.substring(0, primaLetteraSbagliata) + (ok ? a.substring(primaLetteraSbagliata + 1) : "")) >= 0;
}

private boolean presenteConErrore (String chiave , String titolo) {
    String [] titoloSplittato = titolo.split(" ");
    if (titolo.indexOf (chiave) >= 0)
        return true;
    for (String s : titoloSplittato)
        if (mancaUnaLettera (chiave , s) || unaLetteraDiTroppo (chiave, s) || unaLetteraSbagliata (chiave, s))
            return true;

    return false;
}

public boolean suggerimentoDaAggiungere (String titolo) {        
    for (String s : testoSplittato) {
        if (!presenteConErrore (s,titolo))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public SortedSet<String> getSuggerimenti (String testo) {
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        if (/*t != null && */t.isAlive()) {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    }
    testoSplittato = testo.toLowerCase ().split (" ");
    risultati.clear();
    if (testoSplittato.length > 0) {
        setIndice (0);
        for (int i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
            threads [i] = new Thread (runnable);
            threads [i].setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            threads [i].start();
        }
    }
    for (Thread t : threads)
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Searcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    //System.out.println ("FINITO");

    return risultati;                              
}

public static ArrayList<String> getTitoli (String titleFilePath) {
    ArrayList<String> restituire = new ArrayList<String> ();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream (titleFilePath) {}));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine ()) != null) {
            restituire.add (s);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Searcher.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return restituire;
}

}
```

For you it's possible to increase efficiency and velocity of this algorithm?If yes, how it's possible?
Ps. I know that exist dedicates libraries for these functions (like Lucene) but I can't implement with them the autosuggestion function with insertion errors.

Comment: You should probably post your question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a code review request.

Comment: @Maerlyn I don't want prepared code from users but i would suggestions about how to increase efficiency of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the details, your code has two obvious issues:

1. **Linear-time**

Your code loops over every suggestion. If the possible list of suggestions is long, iterating over every single item is going to get unacceptably slow. You might be able to sort the suggestions in some order and/or cut off the maximum number of suggestions.

2. **Contention**

Your parallel threads are not scaling. They are all fighting for the lock held by `getProssimo` and then doing very little work (I imagine), so most of the time, you will get no advantages from multiple threads. Reduce contention by having threads get batches of suggestions at a time.